# Are tuple and record defined the same in the database?

Tags: database, tuples

I am confused with these two terms: tuple and record. Are they defined as the same thing. please help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.

A row, also called a record or tuple, represents a single, implicitly structured data item in a table.